# Paired t-test and presenting multiple data

Tags: t-test, descriptive-statistics

I have 2 observers and 7 rabbit behaviours.

I've got to determine, per behaviour, against observer A and B if there are any significant differences in order to know whether watching pre-recorded rabbit footage is a reliable way of observing rabbit behaviour.

I've done the paired t-tests but I don't know how to present it as I have conducted 7 separate tests comparing the observations of the two observers, the issue is, its very wordy, I need to know if there are other ways of presenting it.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to know how and why paired t-tests were used.  In any event I would be more concerned with not using multiplicity rather than how much you have to write to describe the results.

Comment: My apologies, I have to compare the reliability between observer A and observer B of each behaviour separately. To determine whether our observations are reliable, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the question how many videos each observer watched and how they rated each video?  Having said this, it seems that this problem may call for the computation of a measure of inter-rater reliability. The nature of the measure of inter-rater reliability will depend on the nature of the rating provided by each rater (e.g., continuous rating, nominal rating, ordinal rating).

Comment: There were 8 rabbits in total, each were in pairs with 3 1/2 hours worth of footage that I had to watch. 2 observers watched the same footage and I have to do a statistical analysis to determine whether our observations are reliable.